# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate project loading issue

Tags: intellij-idea

So, today in the morning I closed down IntelliJ(2017.3.3) after doing some programming as usual and everything worked great. Now suddenly when I try to open any of my projects this is the view I am greeted with:[image]

After searching for a solution for this issue I managed to get the projects working by doing the following steps:

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> + -> Import -> The project .iml file
2. File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK -> Java 8 in my case
3. File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project language level -> 8
4. File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project compiler output -> The path to the out folder of the specific project(the whole path from D:\ to it)
5. Navigate to Main class in project structure and alt+enter to add it to run configurations.
6. Finally able to run the project

Now this would be fine if I had to do it once, configuration corruption or whatever happens, but I have to do this every single time I open a project for some reason. I tried restarting my PC, reinstalling 2017.3.3, installing 2018.1 and the issue persists whatever I do. Also there were no visible errors in relation to this issue in any of the above scenarios, steps, installs and so on.

Comment: Jet brains has pretty good support if you post in their community forums. Also, have you recently opened the project using a different Jetbrains IDE?

Comment: @Terminus Yeah planning to post there as well, in the morning, thx. I did not try to open it with a different Jetbrains IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it turns out the issue was related to me using OneDrive to backup my data. I assume OneDrive updated at some point and activated Files On-Demand. The issue is documented [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7619). For me personally a solution that worked was:

1. Right click the OneDrive tray icon
2. Click settings
3. Click the settings tab
4. **Disable** the **Save space and download files as you use them** option under **Files On-Demand**.
5. Wait for your files to sync up completely, IntelliJ project load is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried disabling Themed status bar in Material Theme Advanced Settings and it started working for me.

```
From: IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Material Theme > Advanced Settings > Other Tweaks Tab
```

**Disable "Themed Title Bar"** by unchecking the box here.