# IntelliJ IDEA: Issue with opening projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

I've recently had an issue with IntelliJ IDEA regarding opening my projects. I've tried restarting my PC, deleting IntelliJ along with all settings/cache, and updating the program.

Each time I open a normal .iml stored project it shows no folders.
[image]

After deleting the .idea folder inside the project folder and reopening the project, everything appears to be fine, until I reopen the project once more and I'm back at the same issue.

When opening Maven projects, I get a notification: "non-managed pom.xml file found"
[image]

Now I'll hit "Add as Maven project" and everything will be fine, of course until I reopen the project.

I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake here. This seems to have come out of nowhere and it is impossible to work with.

Comment: Never heard of such problem, what version are you using?

Comment: IIRC, the `.iml` file is the module file, not the project file (a project can contain multiple modules) - so I believe you should be working with the project files instead (inside the `.idea` folder - this folder contains the project settings) - the project settings can be stored in either this folder or a file (`.ipr` I believe)

Comment: Latest version currently, build number IC-181.4445.78 @FilipRistic

Comment: I am opening the project by opening the folder that contains the .idea and .iml file, same as I always have done. @ochi

Comment: Do you use OneDrive? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49701656/2000323

Comment: Yes, this was the issue in my case. Thanks so much for the help! @Andrey